# Trigger to delete rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a Trigger for when records in a log table exceed a certain number of rows I want to start purging them by **x** amount of old records and keeping the new records by a certain date.

Current Query (Pseudocode):

```sql
    declare @date datetime
    SET @date = 'certaindate'

    CREATE TRIGGER PURGE_USERS ON UsersAD FOR DELETE 
    AS DELETE 
    FROM UsersAD WHERE ROWCOUNT(UsersAD) > x and updateDate < @date

    GO
    -- UPDATE: Might have to partition instead of delete.
```

I'm assuming you get my point but neither do I know how to create the trigger in order to start deleting the records nor do I know a good way to figure out when to delete the records.

Appreciate the help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those are that wondering, Instead of creating a **Trigger** I decided to make a **Function** but in SQL Server you must create a Function that will have some sort of return value which is not what I wanted in my case. So after doing some more research, turns out I'd have to make a **Stored Procedure** which will then be executed on a daily basis. Within my query, just implemented it so it will clean up the logs after each week since it gives me enough time to look at what happened to it within the week.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

A better strategy is probably to partition the table.  Partitioning is better than `delete`, because you can drop a partition *much* more efficiently than deleting a bunch of records.

You would especially not want to do a large number of deletes in a trigger, because the table may remained locked for the duration of the insert.  You expect an insert to be fast . . . and suddenly it is really slow.

Normally, partitions would be used to keep a fixed time period of data.  Say, you could have a separate partition for each week and keep the last 100 weeks of data.

You can learn more about partitioning in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for the link. Quick question though, as I'm trying to 'partition' from my audit log due to a lot of testing, how do I exactly know when to partition? There's a lot of factors that come in play. Let's say in 1 day I did 1 week's worth of testing and my trigger won't go off until the week is over. Are we looking at several IF statements now?

Comment: I agree 1000% with Gordon that partitioning is a great approach here. I would go a step further and suggest that you don't want to use a trigger to delete your data at all. This really should be a separate process that you can schedule as frequently as you need too.

Comment: @LifeOfJona . . . You would typically partition by the unit of time that you want to delete -- often a day, week, month, or year.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment.

Typically you wouldn't want to tie your data retention policy to the number of rows in the table, but rather to the time frame that the logged data remains relevant.

Based on your use case and your business rules and, possibly, applicable laws, you'll want to determine if you need the logs for `x` number of hours, days, weeks, months, or years. Once you've made that determination, it's just a matter of setting up a job on an appropriate schedule to remove the records that are no longer needed.

Knowing your retention period will also help in deciding on the granularity for defining table partitions, which, as Gordon Linoff notes, is likely the most efficient way to handle the data removal long-term. It's more effort up front, but your future self will thank you for taking the time to do it when you aren't troubleshooting unexpected slowdowns later on.